# Mono use WebKit with GTK

Tags: c#, mono, webkit, gtk

I have to say that I'm new on Mono, I'm trying to create a project using GTK and making a Window with a WebKit.WebView to load some html page on it.

The problem is: 
I can import the WebKit package in MonoMac project only. In a GTK based project there is no reference to WebKit.

Could someone help me on that?
Many thanks. F.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The WebKit class you use in MonoMac should be a wrapper of this native class. However, on GTK/Linux there is no such native class, so you cannot use WebKit in this way.

But according to Mono wiki, you should be able to use WebKit Sharp,

http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharpDetails